# How to read and write array files in c# winforms

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

```cs
struct Grades
{
    public string studentName;
    public int midtermsGrades;
    public int finalsGrades;
}
//create a 10 row array of Products:
Grades[] allGrades = new Grades[10];
int arrayIndex = 0;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //read Products.txt file and place in array

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        allGrades[x].studentName = "";
        allGrades[x].midtermsGrades = 0;
        allGrades[x].finalsGrades = 0;

    }

    StreamReader productReader = File.OpenText("Grades.txt");
    string[] splitProduct = new string[3];
    string oneProduct = "";
    while (!productReader.EndOfStream)
    {
        oneProduct = productReader.ReadLine();
        splitProduct = oneProduct.Split(',');

        allGrades[arrayIndex].studentName = splitProduct[0];
        StudentIDListBox.Items.Add(splitProduct[0]);
        allGrades[arrayIndex].midtermsGrades = int.Parse(splitProduct[1]);
        allGrades[arrayIndex].finalsGrades = int.Parse(splitProduct[2]);
        arrayIndex++;
    }
    productReader.Close();
}

private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    StreamWriter productWriter = File.CreateText("Grades.txt");
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        //only write to file if product exists
        if (allGrades[x].studentName != "")
        {
            productWriter.Write(allGrades[x].studentName + ",");
            productWriter.Write(allGrades[x].midtermsGrades + ",");
            productWriter.Write(allGrades[x].finalsGrades + ","); ;
        }
    }
    //close
    productWriter.Close();
}
```

I am trying to read in a txt file in my form load event so that a use can make a selection in the list box. When I load the form, the 10 rows show up in the list box, but after closing and reopening, only the first number is present. I need it to save any changes and reload with all 10 rows.

Comment: Do you have 10 rows in the file when you read the first time?  How are you loading the form with 10 rows?  Is it coming from the file or some place else?

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are writing out the text file incorrectly.
At the beginning of each line is the name + numbers.

When you close, you write the data in one line.
So you have to add a line break at the end:

```
//only write to file if product exists
if (allGrades[x].studentName != "")
{
    productWriter.Write(allGrades[x].studentName + ",");
    productWriter.Write(allGrades[x].midtermsGrades + ",");
    productWriter.Write(allGrades[x].finalsGrades + ",");
    productWriter.Write(Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: thank you! this was not included in the sample code so I would've been searching forever!

Comment: No Problem =) To the left of this answer there are voting arrows and below them a tick to accept the answer. I would be happy if you could click on that if you are satisfied with the answer =)

Comment: yeah no problem! I can do that!

Comment: Just a suggestion for (op), instead of accessing the object anytime you need a property etc., get that instance first and then use it :). There's no need to keep getting that same object. Finally I would check the student name a little differently, `!string.IsNullOrEmpty(allGrades[x].studentName)`. The reason for this is because studentName could be an empty string and or just spaces, this would fix that.

Comment: You could also replace the last comma by a line break instead: `productWriter.Write(allGrades[x].finalsGrades + "\r\n");`

Comment: Hello! Apparently I have been banned from asking further questions due to them being a score of 0! If you think my questions could help someone in the future, please upvote my questions! Much appreciated.